# Is there a DOM rendered callback for Knockout.js without templates?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I do something like this :

```
var profileViewModel = new KoProfile(config.data);
ko.applyBindings(profileViewModel , $('#myDiv')[0]);

injectSomeDynamicElements();
```

`#myDiv` contains some elements that I want to push content into after the model is bound.

When applying the new profile Knockout re-renders the html that the model is bound too.

My problem is that when I try to inject the new elements, the DOM has not been updated. I end up injecting images into a div that is about to be cleared by knockout.js

Is there a callback function for DOM update completed without using a template ?

Comment: If you're not using templates, what are you using? Components?

Answer (score 1):

What I doing in this cases is this:

```
OnElementUpdate(element, callback){
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(!$(element).is(':empty')) {
            clear(timer);
            callback();
        }
    }, 100);
}

OnElementUpdate("#myDiv", function(){
    //do whatever you want
}
```